# get new Date() in other timezone in full text string format

Tags: javascript, date, timezone

I need to get Thailand timezone in this format: `Thu Nov 10 2022 14:08:37 GMT+0800 (Malaysia Time)`. I have tried `new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "Asia/Bangkok"})` but didn't get the correct format I want, probably because of the `.toLocaleString()`. Is there a simple way to do it?

Comment: I think, you want to take a look at the options parameter of [toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString), since that is how you can further format the output.

Comment: What format *did* you get…?

Comment: @deceze I get '11/10/2022, 1:38:05 PM' when using .toLocaleString()

Comment: `new Date().toString()` does this work?

Comment: @adiga it didn't change the timezone to Thailand.

Comment: That returns the string in that format based on the local Timezone. You are not in Malaysia Time timezone?

Comment: @adiga Yeah, it returns the string based on the local timezone. Im in Malaysia timezone right now. I want to get Thailand timezone in full text string format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As deceze suggests, you can use *Intl.DateTimeFormat* with suitable options to get the values you want. Then you can use [*formatToParts*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/formatToParts) to reorganise them as you wish, e.g. to replicate the format of *Date.prototype.toString* for any timezone, you can use:

```js
// Return timestamp in same format as Date.prototype.toString
// in designated timezone (IANA representative location)
function toTimezone(tz, date = new Date()) {
  // Get parts except timezone name
  let opts = {
    year: 'numeric',
    month: 'short',
    day: '2-digit',
    weekday: 'short',
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute: '2-digit',
    second: '2-digit',
    timeZone: tz,
    timeZoneName: 'shortOffset',
    hour12: false
  }
  // To get full timezone name
  let opts2 = {
    hour: 'numeric',
    timeZone: tz,
    timeZoneName: 'long'
  }
  let toParts = opts => new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', opts)
         .formatToParts(date)
         .reduce((acc, part) => {
           acc[part.type] = part.value;
           return acc;
         }, Object.create(null));
     
  let {year, month, day, weekday, hour, minute,
       second, timeZoneName} = toParts(opts);
  // Fix offset
  let sign = /\+/.test(timeZoneName)? '+' : '-';
  let [oH, oM] = timeZoneName.substr(4).split(':');
  let offset = `GMT${sign}${oH.padStart(2, '0')}${oM || '00'}`;
  // Get timezone name
  timeZoneName = toParts(opts2).timeZoneName;

return `${weekday} ${month} ${day} ${year} ${hour}:${minute}:${second} ${offset} (${timeZoneName})`;
}

// Examples
['Australia/Adelaide',
 'Asia/Bangkok',
 'Asia/Kolkata',
 'America/New_York',
 'Pacific/Yap',
 'Pacific/Pago_Pago'
].forEach(tz => console.log(toTimezone(tz)));
```

Support for some options like *shortOffset* may not be ubiquitous yet. A formatting library with timezone support is a simpler (and more reliable) option. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the locale string formatter with a whole bunch of [options](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat#options):

```js
console.log(new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', {
  timeZone: 'Asia/Bangkok',
  weekday: 'short',
  year: 'numeric',
  month: 'short',
  day: 'numeric',
  hour: 'numeric',
  minute: 'numeric',
  second: 'numeric',
  timeZoneName: 'short',
  hour12: false
}));
```

However, the exact format it will output will always be dependent on the locale used and the browser's understanding of how dates should be formatted for that locale. If you want more control over the exact formatting, you'll need to cobble it together yourself:

```js
const date = new Date();

const time = date.toLocaleString('en-US', {
  timeZone: 'Asia/Bangkok',
  hour: 'numeric',
  minute: 'numeric',
  second: 'numeric',
  timeZoneName: 'short',
  hour12: false
});

const weekday = date.toLocaleString('en-US', {
  timeZone: 'Asia/Bangkok',
  weekday: 'short'
});

console.log(`${weekday} ${date.getFullYear()} ... ${time}`);
```

If that seems too complicated, use some 3rd party library like [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/), which can simplify that a bit.